# Lightning Communities: Page load complete event

Tags: lightning, community

We use a Salesforce community for a public support website. We're having a lot of headaches caused by the single-page nature of how Community pages load. For example, a third-party script runs on the page to add an iframe to a div element, but the script fires before the div is loaded which causes it to fail. Another example is our custom framework sets up listeners on certain elements via class, but those elements haven't loaded yet when the framework script runs. Is there any way to cause these scripts to wait until everything on the page is loaded fully?

Obviously on a normal webpage, the DOMContentLoaded and window.ready events would suffice for this, but these both fire well before any content from Lightning has loaded underneath.

I'm aware you can hook into a RenderedCallback in LWCs, but our content is mainly within Knowledge records or Builder pages that exist outside custom LWCs.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: It sounds like a lot of hacks! It would be great if you can provide more detail about how the Iframe, community and the custom framework are related? Maybe a visual representation

Comment: Let's simplify it down to just the iframe works first, it's representative of all the problems. We have a target <div> container with a class "iframe-target." This HTML is included as an "HTML Editor" component in the Community Builder. 

We place the third-party script in the <head> of the page via the Advanced menu in the Builder settings. The script executes before the HTML Editor's content has loaded on the page, so the script cannot find the <div> target and thus does not insert its iframe.